# Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Not sure why this code isn't running. Copied all required snippets from Firebase and my button is firing. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong? Github is making me write more stuff in here so here.

Thanks!

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Auth</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="googleAuth()">SIGN UP</button>

<script>

  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

  var googleAuth = function() {
    console.log(firebase);
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.
      var user = result.user;
      // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      var email = error.email;
      // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
      var credential = error.credential;
      // ...
    });
};


</script>








  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBeJIaAAD5-vK0kBDTRH6Y6_1ByVE3erJY",
      authDomain: "fir-chat-d28be.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://fir-chat-d28be.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "fir-chat-d28be.appspot.com",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must follow the instructions in log:

```
The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
```

See how it says signInWithPopup will not work without your domain added in Firebase console

Comment: I'm viewing the html file in a browser so I can't add a domain in firebase. I also didn't get any errors in the console.

Comment: What is your domain in the browser?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/MGover/Desktop/index.html

Comment: You need to run local web server such as Apache. Next, you will place the index.html into the web root then go to localhost in the browser. Firebase automatically whitelists localhost for OAuth redirects so it should work at that point.

Comment: Ok I'll try it in a little bit here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did this clarify the issue for you? Please accept my answer if so

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions I listed when I was having a similar error, this will enable you to solve the oAuth issue.

[Firebase GAS webapp Google popup disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437930/firebase-gas-webapp-google-popup-disappears)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, but if you run that as an HTML file, you'll get an error similar to "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http or https".

I'd suggest you to take advantage of [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) feature. You can easily deploy and host your app's static assets like HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.. Moreover, it's free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience ( just for advice ), dont use firebase auth with provider like google or facebook. use email and password auth for better security. you can use [FirebaseUi](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web), verry easy to understand, and you can copy-paste if you like. if you use Google auth, every user who have google account can access your apps, read, write, delete, and update. except, you have better experience with Firebase Rules.